# How can I use PnP Powershell to enable custom script in a subsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, pnp-powershell, sub-site

My problem is enabling custom script with `DenyAddAndCustomizePages`.
A two-line script can describe my problem.

**Background**: I was using `Set-SPOSite` to enable it like this:

```
Set-SPOSite $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
```

This worked fine for sites with URLs of the form
`https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite`, i.e. top-level sites in the collection.
When I used it on a subsite of MySite, it gave me an error:
(The URL was `"https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/Subsite1"`)

The error was:

> Set-SPOSite: The managed path sites/Mysite is not a managed path in this tenant.

(It was not seeing past `Mysite` in the URL).
I found an explanation that appeared to make sense, that `Get/Set-SPOSite` cmdlets only work at the top-level of the site collection. And suggested to use PnP PowerShell.

So I tried this script:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminCenterURL -Interactive
Set-PnPTenantSite -Identity $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages:$False
```

It works fine on top-level sites, but on subsites I get the same error:

> The managed path sites/MySite is not a managed path in this tenant.

Is there any way of scripting with PnP PowerShell to enable custom scripts on subsites?

(Pls excuse any formatting errors. First post here).

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can set this setting at "subsite" level, you have to set it at "site" level only. Can you please explain what are you trying to do exactly on subsite so that you want to enable this setting?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP: Thank you. Your question tapped into my lack of   understanding and a wrong assumption. My document library transfer script had failed on this classic site collection subsite and I had assumed it was caused by custom script setting because of a similar error earlier. It is set at site level, so my question premise was wrong. I'll get back to troubleshooting - thanks for the reset!

Comment: You're welcome! Can you share more details about the "document library transfer script"? What exactly are you trying to do and what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments section above,

I don't think you can set this setting at "sub site" level, you have to set it at "site (site collection)" level only.

You can either enable it using SharePoint Online PowerShell or PnP PowerShell or CLI for Microsoft 365.

Here is an example using SharePoint Online PowerShell:

```
# SharePoint online admin center URL
$adminCenterUrl = "https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/"

# SharePoint online site URL
$siteUrl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect"

# Connect to SharePoint online admin center
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminCenterUrl

# Allow custom scripts on SharePoint online site
Set-SPOSite $siteUrl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0

# Verify that custom scripts are enabled on SharePoint online site
Get-SPOSite $siteUrl | select DenyAddAndCustomizePages
```

You can find the script examples using PnP PowerShell and CLI for Microsoft 365 in this article: [Allow use of custom scripts in SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/05/18/allow-use-of-custom-scripts-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/).

Answer (score 0):

Custom script can only be enabled in the site collection level.

In the SharePoint admin center, you can choose to allow users to run custom script on OneDrive (referred to as "personal sites") or on all classic team sites they create.

Go to Settings in the SharePoint admin center -> Classic settings page at the end of page -> Enable custom script.

[image]

Or you use PowerShell to enable custom script for all site collections.

```
#Parameters
$TenantURL =  "https://Crescent.sharepoint.com"
  
#Get Credentials to connect
$Credential = Get-Credential
  
#Frame Tenant Admin URL from Tenant URL
$TenantAdminURL = $TenantURL.Insert($TenantURL.IndexOf("."),"-admin")
 
#Connect to Admin Center
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TenantAdminURL -Credentials $Credential
  
#Get All Site collections 
$Sites = Get-PnPTenantSite
 
#Iterate through all sites
$Sites | ForEach-Object {
    Write-host "Processing Site Collection:"$_.URL
 
    #Enable Custom Script
    If ($_.DenyAddAndCustomizePages -ne "Disabled")
    {
        Set-PnPTenantSite -Identity $_.URL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages:$false
        Write-host "`tCustom Script has been Enabled!" -f Green
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-host "`tCustom Script is Already Enabled!" -f Yellow
    }
}
```